# Have Indian forces been shooting hundreds of Kashmiris in their eyes, with pellet guns or shotguns?

Tags: military, india, police

According [to AA](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/asia-pacific/kashmir-india-using-pellet-guns-to-maim-blind-kill-/1963597)

> Over 6,200 people were wounded by pellets – 782 with eye injuries – between July 2016 and February 2017, according to Mehbooba Mufti, former chief minister of the region.
>
> “The Indian government should cease the use of shotguns firing metal pellets and review its crowd control techniques to meet international standards,” the statement concluded.

Is this true?

Comment: When I read this, the claim in the title reads differently from the claim in the quote.  When I read the quote, I get the impression that Indian forces have been using birdshot or similar, that lots of people have been wounded, and a fraction of them have caught a pellet in the eye. When I read the title it sounds like they have been specifically aiming for eyes. Perhaps the claim could be clearer?

Comment: @JackB: to loosely quote from a US official "intent matters, but results matter too". Since this is Skeptics, I'm asking about the results, since intent is harder to measure, so generally off-topic here.

Comment: The wording could still be clearer. Perhaps something like "Have hundreds of Kashmiris been hit in the eyes by pellet gun or shotguns from Indian forces?"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### 782 is near the minimum with eye injuries

The title of [A series of 777 pellet gun ocular injuries over a 4-month period in Kashmir](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9789860/) is pretty self-explanatory. The authors reviewed records from 777 patients with injuries from taking a pellet to the eye from a "tertiary hospital in Srinagar, India, between July and November 2016" (a smaller subset of the timeframe the claim in question covers). As the "Limitations" section says, this number does not include people who went to other hospitals or did not seek any medical treatment.

Note: We can't conclude that the shots were aimed at the eyes specifically from this because these guns "propel hundreds of small metal pellets, or birdshot, capable of piercing the body and eye", all in a single scattering shot. The eyes are the most vulnerable, but there are plenty of other injuries from these guns reported on other areas of the body.